# Preventing u- tube effect on a fluid

Tags: fluid-mechanics, pressure, forces

Say you have two cylinders, one fixed bigger outer cylinder and the other is free (lets say a straw with a tapered end 1/3 from the bottom. As you push the straw into the medium (fairly dense viscous medium (not water)), the medium starts to come out the top of the straw. Can you put a certain density of fluid in the straw to continuously add more straws until you reach the bottom of the bigger cylinder without it flowing over the top, particularly when the straw is higher than the fixed cylinder.

Comment: Won't the viscosity cause the level in the straw to be lower than the level in the outer cylinder?

Comment: Even as you're pushing the straw down into the larger cylinder? And when the liquid (connected through bottom of straw obviously) is uniform rheology why does it come out the straw top at a higher elevation?

Comment: Are you assuming the free surface pressures are different?

Comment: No, they're both at atmospheric conditions

Comment: I don't see how the medium would go out of the top of the straw assuming the top is above the free surface in the bigger cylinder.

Comment: The free surface of the bigger is below the smaller cylinder...